# Run External application outside the browser like BitTorrent

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for JavaScript to detect whether an application (such as BitTorrent) is installed and if so, can it can be launched by clicking on a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Javascript, it works with handlers.

Handlers are in your browser and trigger events when a special protocol is clicked / called.

e.g.: if you open a `magnet://` link, it will trigger the handler for magnet. And the handler is connected with the bittorrent application.

So:

first question: No

second question: Yes (with a handler [need to be installed in browser])